# ListView invokes the `get_template_names` without calling it

Tags: django

I am reading the Django source code of `ListView`: 
[django/list.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/list.py)

```
class MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin(TemplateResponseMixin):
    template_name_suffix = '_list'
    def get_template_names(self):
       try:
            names = super().get_template_names()

class ListView(MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin, BaseListView):
    """
    Render some list of objects, set by `self.model` or `self.queryset`.
    `self.queryset` can actually be any iterable of items, not just a queryset.
    """
```

When I define `ListView`, `template_name` is assigned automatically

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    pass
```

I assume there should have a assigning step in `MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin` as

```
class MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin(TemplateResponseMixin):
    template_name_suffix = '_list'
    def get_template_names(self):
       try:
            names = super().get_template_names()
            ....
    template_name = self.get_template_names()
```

How it invoke the `get_template_names` without call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_template_names` is called in [`render_to_response`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L115) method of `TemplateResponseMixin` class, which is superclass of `MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin`.